# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined (Node js simple calculator)

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is **a piece** of  my simple calculator Node js program. I have a background in C++ but I am a javascript/node beginner.

```
/

/ Defining the IP Address of our server
var ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";

// Defining the port on which we want to listen
var portNumber = "52000";

// Importing necessary library files
var httpModule = require("http");

// Creating our server's main method
httpModule.createServer(function serviceRequest (request, response) {

  // Check what file the user has requested and take necessary action
  var queryString = new String(request.url);

  // We're expecting URLs of the following type:
  // action=add&number1=3&number2=6

  var keyValuePairs = queryString.split("&"); // Splitting the query string based on & delimiter

  // Now keyValuePairs[0] contains our action
  var action = keyValuePairs[0].replace("/","").split("=")[1]; // extracting the action specified in the URL
  var firstNumber = new String(keyValuePairs[1].split("&")).split("=")[1] ||  "0"; // extracting the first number
  var secondNumber = new String(keyValuePairs[2].split("&")).split("=")[1] || "0"; // extracting the second number

  // calling the method to get the result
  var result = getResult(action.toLowerCase(), Number(firstNumber) , Number(secondNumber));

  // HTML which we will display to the user
  var htmlContent = "<html><b>" + action + "(" + firstNumber + "," + secondNumber + ") = <b>" + result + "</b></html>";

  // write the response
  response.end(htmlContent);
 }
).listen(portNumber, ipAddress);

 // Utility method to perform an operation on 2 numbers. Helps to modularize code
function getResult(operation, number1, number2)
{
 var result = 0;

 if(operation == "add")
  result = number1 + number2;

 else if(operation == "subtract")
  result = number1 - number2;

 else if(operation == "multiply")
  result = number1 * number2;

 else if(operation == "divide" && number2 != 0)
  result = number1 / number2;

 return result;
}
```

**I've tried some input URL such as:**

http://127.0.0.1:52000/action=add&number1=18&number2=6

http://127.0.0.1:52000/action=divide&number1=18&number2=6

and the program works fine but neverthless I have the following error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined on this line :**

var firstNumber = new String(keyValuePairs[1].split("&")).split("=")[1] ||  "0"; // extracting the first number

**What is the source of the error?**

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue.  Everything works as intended for all example URLs.  Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `keyValuePairs[1].split("&")`, you shouldn't call split, since it already has all ampersands removed.

Comment: I have replaced var firstNumber and var secondNumber with respectively:                      
`var firstNumber = (new String(keyValuePairs[1])).split("=")[1] ||  "0";`   and                     `var secondNumber = (new String(keyValuePairs[2])).split("=")[1] || "0";` .                        But now I have the following error on this line                                                                   `var result = getResult(action.toLowerCase(), Number(firstNumber) , Number(secondNumber));`       **Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

Comment: I have solved the above issue **Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined** by simply replacing in `var result` `action.toLowerCase()` whit `action` alone